# ksvideosrc becomes videotestst in Python program

Tags: python, gstreamer, pygobject

I'm trying to use `ksvideosrc` to test a simple video playing program using gstreamer and python. I can use the command line in Windows to set up a simple pipeline to play my webcam

```
gst-launch-1.0 ksvideosrc ! autovideosink
```

This works just fine. My python program can connect to a `videotestsrc` element and display that in my GUI window, but when I try to do the same thing with `ksvideosrc`, I still get the `videotestsrc` video.

I tried the program listed in

[List device-names available for video capture from ksvideosrc in gstreamer 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30440134/list-device-names-available-for-video-capture-from-ksvideosrc-in-gstreamer-1-0)

The program runs, but it exits with `device_index=1`, so it doesn't find any.

Why does `Gst.ElementFactory.make('ksvideosrc')` give me a `videotestsrc` element?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I should mention that I'm using Python3.4.

Comment: I tried boiling my program down to the basics. I connected to ksvideosrc and piped it to autovideosink. When I set the pipeline to PLAYING, I got a window with my webcam video, so it must be something with me trying to put the video into a Gtk.Layout. This works with videotestsrc, so why not ksvideosrc?